# Test framework for system test

Tags: java, system-testing, black-box-testing

i'm looking for a test framework (preverably in Java) to create system tests.
The system i need to test is an ESB offering multiple http endpoint for receiving and pushing messages, a JMS Server and a JBoss-Application Server with a Database at the end.
I want to create test scenarios which defines incoming messages to the ESB, the response which should be send to the request and the expected values in the database.

The chain is:

```
http(ESB) -> JMS -> JBoss -> Database
```

but also:

```
Database -> JBoss -> JMS -> ESB(http)
```

The tests should be implemented as JUnit test or in a way that they can be fired by Hudson.
It would be nice, if it is also possible to test the exchanged JMS messages.
I used to work with a framework that fits the needs, but this was in a different company, and, it was self written and sometimes a pain in the a..
I know i'm not the only and first one who needs something like this =)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar using JUnit test. The project was maven-based and I ran it on Hudson. I used [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) for test execution and [maven-sql-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/) to set clean DB on each execution.

Hope it helps...